# How to calculate all the combinations between different arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, combinations, permutation, calculator

Let's say I have this 3 arrays:

```
 Shirts [White, Navy, Light Blue, Gray],
 Pants [Black, Navy, Gray],
 Ties [Houndstooth, Polka Dot, Herringbone, Solid]
```

What should I do to get this result

```
 White Shirt with Black Pants and a Houndstooth Tie,
 White Shirt with Black Pants and a Polka Dot Tie,
 White Shirt with Black Pants and a Herringbone Tie,
 White Shirt with Black Pants and a Solid Tie,

 White Shirt with Navy Pants and a Houndstooth Tie,
 White Shirt with Navy Pants and a Polka Dot Tie,
 White Shirt with Navy Pants and a Herringbone Tie,
 White Shirt with Navy Pants and a Solid Tie,

 And so on,
 And so on...
```

Comment: I'm a bit rusty with JS, so please explain what you do.

Comment: Do you have code for this? If not, go write some first and try it out, then we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What have you tried? There are 75 possible combinations with the Arrays you posted.

Comment: The most basic solution would probably to use 3 nested `for` loops to iterate through everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop over one of them, outputting the index for each array. You'll need to use loops inside of loops for this, using differing indexes for each loop:

```js
var shirts = ["White", "Navy", "Light Blue", "Gray"];
var pants = ["Black", "Navy", "Gray"];
var ties = ["Houndstooth", "Polka Dot", "Herringbone", "Solid"];

for (var i = 0; i < shirts.length; i++) {
  var start = shirts[i] + " shirt with ";
  for (var j = 0; j < pants.length; j++) {
    var middle = pants[j] + " pants and a ";
    for (var k= 0; k < ties.length; k++) {
      var end = ties[k] + " tie.<br />";
     document.write(start + middle + end);
    }
  }
}
```

You can get the total by simply multiplying the **[`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)** of the three arrays together, assigning the total to a variable, and then outputting that variable:

```js
var shirts = ["White", "Navy", "Light Blue", "Gray"];
var pants = ["Black", "Navy", "Gray"];
var ties = ["Houndstooth", "Polka Dot", "Herringbone", "Solid"];
var total_combinations = shirts.length * pants.length * ties.length;
document.write("Total number of combinations: " + total_combinations);
```

To get a **random** output, you can use **[`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)** in conjunction with **[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)** on the array indexes as follows:

```js
var shirts = ["White", "Navy", "Light Blue", "Gray"];
var pants = ["Black", "Navy", "Gray"];
var ties = ["Houndstooth", "Polka Dot", "Herringbone", "Solid"];

var random_shirt = shirts[Math.floor(Math.random()*shirts.length)];
var random_pants = pants[Math.floor(Math.random()*pants.length)];
var random_tie = ties[Math.floor(Math.random()*ties.length)];

document.write(random_shirt + " shirt with " + random_pants + " pants and a " + random_tie + " tie.");
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How can I print this in html?

Comment: You can use `document.write()`. I've just updated my answer to cover this :)

Comment: Totally different question now. How do I output one of this random combos when clicking a button?

Comment: You're awesome. Please forgive my javascript ignorance. I barely have used it. Just as a final question, if you will, how can I print a square with the color/texture of the garment?

Comment: That's actually rather complicated to do, and to combine that logic with the initial question would make it far **too broad**, and make the question '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please break each action you are trying to do down into a specific action, and ask each one as new, individual question. You can link to this question with [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702972) if it helps to explain your point :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151995/discussion-between-ferrius-and-obsidian-age).

Answer (score 2):

Just to calculate? That's easy.

Multiply them. `5*3*4=60` variants.

If you need to have all the variants as a text:

```js
var shirts = ['White', 'Navy', 'Light Blue', 'Gray'];
    var pants = ['Black', 'Navy', 'Grey'];
    var ties = ['Houndstooth', 'Polka Dot', 'Herringbone', 'Solid'];
    
    for(var s in shirts) {
      for(var p in pants) {
        for(var t in ties) {
            document.write(shirts[s] + ' Shirt with ' + pants[p] + ' Pants and a ' + ties[t] + ' Tie<br>');
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: I would like to print it in html, but `document.write` doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this queston. Read the manual, man. Try `<div id=out></div>` and `document.getElementById('out').innerHTML+="string"`

Comment: FYI it's considered [bad practice to use `for/in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) for iterating through arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But that's OK to use it in this simple case.